# compactMap vs flatMap, Swift

Tags: swift, functional-programming

can anyone describe this behaviour of flatMap vs compactMap? Isn't compactMap just renamed flatMap ? because I found a case where they are acting different

```
struct Person {
  let cars: [String]?
  let name: String
  let surname: String
  let age: Int
}

let people = [
  Person(cars: nil, name: "Adam", surname: "Bayer", age: 19),
  Person(cars: ["Audi","BMW"], name: "Michael", surname: "Knight", age: 40),
  Person(cars: ["BMW", "Mercedes", "Audi"], name: "Freddy", surname: "Krueger", age: 62)
]

let flatCars = people.flatMap { $0.cars }.flatMap { $0 }
let flatCompactCars = people.flatMap { $0.cars }.compactMap { $0 }

let compactFlatCars = people.compactMap { $0.cars }.flatMap { $0 }
let compactCars = people.compactMap { $0.cars }.compactMap { $0 }
```

and this is what it prints

```
flatMap flatMap:        ["Audi", "BMW", "BMW", "Mercedes", "Audi"]
flatMap compactMap:     [["Audi", "BMW"], ["BMW", "Mercedes", "Audi"]]
compactMap flatMap:     ["Audi", "BMW", "BMW", "Mercedes", "Audi"]
compactMap compactMap:  [["Audi", "BMW"], ["BMW", "Mercedes", "Audi"]]
```

can anyone tell why when I use `compactMap` nested array is not flatten?

Comment: They have not been renamed. There are 2 because they are different. Previously it used to be ambiguous which of the 2 overloads would be used depending on if the objects were optional or not. This created a great confusion in some cases. Bottom line: NO, compact map is not just a rename of flat map but is a rename of one of the functionality that used to be in flat map.

Comment: have a look [here](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0187-introduce-filtermap.md#motivation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There used to be two different functions named `flatMap` for sequences; one to filter out nil values and one to join sequences. Now, *one* of these (the `nil` variant) has been renamed to `compactMap`

Comment: There are actually 3 variants. There is also one on `Optional<T>` which has not changed either.

Comment: @Sulthan That’s true. I was only referring to the sequence related `flatMap` variants. I updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: My apologies for nitpicking.